# What prevents me to accelerate an object to near light speed in space?

Tags: speed-of-light, speed

As far my limited knowledge go, things in space aren't slow down unless something interferes with them, so what prevents me to build a spaceship powered by nuclear power that will keep accelerating until we get to the limits of physics?

Like the voyager ship that is now outside our solar system, it had by know plenty time to accelerate to be much more faster than it's right now (about 17030 m/s)?

Wouldn't that greatly reduces the time you need to get to a distant star, since you can increase your speed exponentially ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far my limited knowledge go, things in space aren't slow down
>   unless something interferes with them, so what prevents me to build a
>   spaceship powered by nuclear power that will keep accelerating until
>   we get to the limits of physics?
>
> Like the voyager ship that is now outside our solar system, it had by
>   know plenty time to accelerate to be much more faster than it's right
>   now (about 17030 m/s)?

You can accelerate near to light speed, but the nearer you get the more difficult it will be. If the object accelerating has mass $M$ then in order to accelerate from speed 0 to speed $v$ you will have had to supply at least
$$
KE=Mc^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} - Mc^2
$$
amount of energy (this expression is the total energy minus the rest energy, i.e., the relativistic kinetic energy). Clearly this expression approaches infinity as the speed approaches light speed and you can not supply an infinite amount of energy. So, the more energy you can supply the closer you can get, but even a nuclear power plant can not supply an infinite amount of energy.

> Wouldn't that greatly reduces the time you need to get to a distant
>   star, since you can increase your speed exponentially ?

Since the energy involves square roots and quadratic functions of the velocity, the speed can not be an exponential function of the energy. It is much less quickly increasing and indeed approaches the speed of light at infinity.

Comment: This means that an object will eventually stop accelerating even if have your engines at maximum and nothing slowing you in space? That's what I really don't understand

Comment: I've explained the reasoning in terms of energy, but I think you want it explained in terms of a constant thrust (force) coming from your "engines at maxmimum". In that case what happens is that the inertia is not just E/c^2, rather it is E/c^2/(1-v^2/c^2). Effectively a relativistic increase in inertia is why you can't get past light speed. You will keep on speeding up but at an every slower rate as you approach the speed of light even though your thrusters are still maxed out. See for example: http://www.oberlin.edu/physics/dstyer/Modern/RelativisticDynamics.pdf at page 42 and beyond.

Comment: @Freedo, according to the accelerometer on the spaceship, it is accelerating as long as the engines are on; according to any inertial observer, it is accelerating as long as the engines are on.  In other words, the spaceship doesn't eventually stop accelerating.  The key insight is that the coordinate acceleration of the spacecraft *approaches* zero as the spacecraft's speed, according to any inertial observer, approaches *c*.

Answer (score 1):

> Wouldn't that greatly reduces the time you need to get to a distant star, since you can increase your speed exponentially?

In addition to *hft's answer*, due to relativistic kinetic energy $KE$ , assuming you use high constant thrust your actual *acceleration* would start tailing off quickly at relativistic speeds, so you certainly couldn't *"increase your speed exponentially"*. Quite the opposite, in fact.

Comment: Heh. I was just adding that to my answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> so what prevents me to build a spaceship powered by nuclear power that
>   will keep accelerating until we get to the limits of physics?

Now matter how long the spaceship is able to accelerate (as measured by an accelerometer attached to the spaceship), there is *always* an inertial reference frame in which the spaceship is instantaneously at rest.

Indeed, at any instant, there are an infinity of inertial reference frames in which the spaceship has a speed arbitrarily close to $c$.

So, it isn't clear to me what you mean by "until we get to the limit physics".

Certainly, if the spaceship accelerated (linearly) long enough, the CMB would become an intense gamma ray beam in front of the spacecraft so that is at least one type of limit.